# Dismissed before start date due financial history in background check

Tags: germany, labor-law

A month back I signed a contract with a company as a software developer, the company in question is a financial institution based in Sweden with a german office.

Recently they finished their background check and found that I have a small personal debt, around 200 euro. I have read on various places that such background checks in Germany is illegal. Also that this is not a valid reason for dismissal, as I wouldn't be handling any finances for the company.

My question is if I have understood it correctly, namely that:

1. Is it legal to perform background checks into financial/credit history
2. Is this a valid reason for dismissal, as it's still a financial company.

Comment: Did you sign anything saying "I have no debts other than these" or words to that effect?

Comment: No, at least not to my knowledge. I tried to look for something like this in the contract.